# Pass a powershell command to a specific process with a specifiic PID

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, powershell

I am trying to write a form, where I have an option to open an exe with different sessions, each session with 2 cores. The program I need this to happen with is called Revit 2015. I have figured a way to include it in my app, Revit 2015 work perfectly with:

> cmd.exe /c start "Revit" /affinity XX "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit
>   2015\Revit.exe

in my visual project it would have it like this:

```
Private Sub GPG4B1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GPG4B1.Click
    If Not Me.RadioButton1.Checked And Not Me.RadioButton2.Checked Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select a Revit version")
    Else
        If IsNothing(Me.ComboBoxGP.SelectedItem) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please select the Cores")
        Else
            If Me.RadioButton1.Checked And Me.ComboBoxGP.Text = "1 Core" Then
                Shell("cmd.exe /c start ""Revit"" /affinity 00000001 ""C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2015\Revit.exe""")
            End If

            If Me.RadioButton1.Checked And Me.ComboBoxGP.Text = "2 Cores" Then
                Shell("cmd.exe /c start ""Revit"" /affinity 9 ""C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2015\Revit.exe""")
            End If

            If Me.RadioButton1.Checked And Me.ComboBoxGP.Text = "3 Cores" Then
                Shell("cmd.exe /c start ""Revit"" /affinity 15 ""C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2015\Revit.exe""")
            End If
```

so a user would have chosen the version of Revit with a radio button tool from my form, and from a combo box, he would have chose the set of cores he would like to use.
For some reason, this doesn't cut it with Revit 2016! Using the same command line would just end up doing nothing to the affinity of the session of Revit I am trying to pass that command line

But the internet was generous, so I found a work around for Revit 2016, and that is by passing a PowerShell command line after Revit has been launched, so what I am trying to figure out now, on how to pass this PowerShell command to Revit 2016 to a particular session, without affecting other sessions
This is the PowerShell line:

> $Process = Get-Process Revit; $Process.ProcessorAffinity=255

So with this PowerShell command line, I was able to pick point which cores I can use with Revit 2016. Next step would be to incorporate this in my form, but as you would already know, if I pass this at any point, this will affect other "Revit.exe" sessions, and bring them to the same cores I specified in the command line. SO I had to think of a way to differentiate the processes of Revit from each other by the PID, and greatly vb.net makes it simple by using this:

> myProcess.Id

and with this code:

```
   myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2016\Revit.exe"
    myProcess.Start()
    TextBox1.Text = myProcess.Id
```

I was able to accomplish, opening Revit, and capturing its PID.
My question would be, how do I make a use of the process ID for a specific session and pass that PowerShell command to that process which I just started with that specific ID?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to start a process is contained the `System.Diagnostics` namespace. One thing you could do is feed this command line to launch the app to the [Process.Start(String,String) method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx), which returns a process object. Therein, if the user has permission, you can also set the affinity (see the Process class - this is what your PowerShell code is doing).

The MSDN code sample should be sufficient, but if not, please feel free to get in touch!

Comment: @user5957902 Thank you for your Answer, I appreciate it. I have tried a sample code with Process.Start(string,String) method. But I am not sure how I will incorporate the PowerShell line yet! I guess I will keep digging, thank you

Comment: @user5957902 I need your help :( will you please give me a sample of what could help me?